# Include a pie chart in LaTeX beamer template

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgf-pie

I want to draw a pie chart in LaTeX beamer template, but something wrong happened.

The code is as follows:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xcolor}

 \begin{frame}{complicated family structure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
#2\printnumbertrue
\else
\printnumberfalse
\fi}
\newif\ifprintnumber
\pie[rotate=40,radius=4,color={black!30, black!40, black!50, black!60,black!70,red!80},before number=\printonlylargeenough{90},
    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi]{3.3/, 3.1/, 1.2/Others, 1.1/,1.0/,90.3/Didi}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

I don't know why this happened as when I draw the pie chart in a normal template, nothing wrong happened.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: PowerPoint is not LaTeX, I think you're using `beamer` documentclass, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to add `[fragile]` as `frame` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Complicated family structure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
#2\printnumbertrue
\else
\printnumberfalse
\fi}
\newif\ifprintnumber
\pie[rotate=40,radius=4,color={black!30, black!40, black!50, black!60,black!70,red!80},before number=\printonlylargeenough{90},
    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi]{3.3/, 3.1/, 1.2/Others, 1.1/,1.0/,90.3/Didi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much！！！

Comment: @AuroraJoy You're welcome!